# Set process priority to High: Dangerous?

Tags: windows, process, priority

I have read that setting something to realtime is a big no-no, so I am not going to do that.  But I do have an application that I need to make sure always has the highest priority on my system as it is critical for the rest of the applications I am running.  Is there any danger in setting the priority to high, which is one level below realtime?

Also, how would I be able to do this by changing the shortcut target?  What is the command?

Comment: "Above normal" (windows 7) setting is safer. Some discussion here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663993/what-is-the-realtime-setting-for-for-process-priority

Comment: It's very dangerous. The major problem is [priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) which results in the higher-priority process actually getting an effectively lower priority because it can be [indefinitely blocked by a lower priority process](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/mbj/mars_pathfinder/mars_pathfinder.html).

Comment: As mentioned "Realtime" is not necessarily bad so long as your process is well behaved and only runs when it needs and sleeps when it does not, otherwise it can (and will) prevent other tasks from running entirely.

Comment: @David Schwartz, Cutler designed the Windows scheduler to avoid deadlock due to priority inversion.  From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96418, "The Windows NT scheduler solves this problem by randomly boosting the priority of threads that are ready to run (in this case the low priority lock-holders). The low priority threads run long enough to let go of their lock (exit the critical section), and the high- priority thread gets the lock back. If the low-priority thread doesn't get enough CPU time to free its lock the first time, it will get another chance on the next scheduling round ."

Comment: @NicoleHamilton So that's why sometimes a program will open a few instances at once if it didn't open on the first click (and you clicked a few times), because of high load?

Comment: Probably helpful to know what your process does and why you think it needs to be high priority.

Comment: I would not say that it is dangerous. I once wrote a little program that boosts performance to a single process of choice. How it works is that it fetches a list of all processes running in windows, then sets priority of all of them to low, sets affinity of all of them to single core and then it sets priority of a chosen one process to realtime and its affinity to all cores. This is as extreme boost as it gets. It sets priority to low and affinity to single core of all processes, including system processes. Only about 6-7 system processes are not changed because they are protected.

Comment: (ntoskrnl.exe and similar core windows processes). And what is amazing is that even such extreme configuration works for me. It is stable. But benefits are just amazing. For example, it takes about 250 hours for a complete backup of my system with normal settings. Once i used this extreme boost program which i wrote to give boost to my backup application, and guess how long it took for a complete backup to be performed? Just over 30 hours! So, from 250 hours to 30 hours, it was worth this questionable and extreme configuration.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, i am not saying that you should do this, to set realtime priority and maximal number of cores to single application and single core and low priority to all other programs, including system programs. This can be dangerous. If that application which has realtime priority encounters a bug and enteres infinite loop, it will use almost 100% of processor for itself so it will be next thing to impossible to kill that application other by pressing the reset button on your pc. And it did happen to me before when i had single core processor and windows xp.

Comment: But lately, i did not experience this, now when i use multicore processor and windows server 2019. So, even such extreme configuration should be stable as long as application does not go into infinite loop and as long as you have multicore processor, this extreme configuration can have speed boost of up to 900%, as i experienced. So, to answer your question, as long as you have multicore processor no it is not dangerous to even set single process to realtime, just it would be probably wise that you uncheck one core in affinity settings of that process just to be on a safe side, eek.

Comment: But, if you wish to set it to high, then there will be no problems, even if you leave it running on all cores or a single core processor. Nothing will happen except that other applications will become little slower when that application which priority you set to high is using processor intensively, but that is to be expected. And if you feal adventurous and can take a little (not too much) risk, you can even try (at your own risk, of course) my ultra extreme boost settings which i described above). The potential benefits and boost are just mind blowing.

Comment: I mean, you are the master of your pc, Noone can say you that you can not do something of you want to. Such extreme configuration as i sometimes set can be dangerous, but the worst thing that can happen is your computer to freeze. Wow, big thing. So, if you do not have some data in random access memory which you can not loose, you are ok to play with all settings. You can do whatever you want. Experiment. If it fails, fine, it is your computer, you will fix it. No need to be afraid of doing risky things if it is your computer and you do not have any important data to loose

Comment: Your computer will not explode whatever you do (in windows), so, do not be afraid to experiment. That is the best way to learn. And, setting priority to high is perfectly safe thing to do. I would even do realtime. And of course, setting priority of a process does not automatically mean that it is going to work faster and certainly not 900% faster. It only means that windows will reserve more system resources to that process, if process needs them. But in wast majority of cases, especially if process is using a lot of resources, processor time mainly, you will get a speed boost.

Comment: 900% speed bust is my top result which i managed to achieve. But i only achieved it by being brave and taking a risk of configuring processes to such extreme configuration which would make some people here sick, especially those people who suggest that 'above normal' should be your limit. Setting your process to high will certainly not give you such extreme results, but it would certainly speed it up. So, i hope that my experience was interesting to hear and that it encouraged you to experiment a little more. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realtime isn't necessarily a "no-no". It just might starve other processes out of CPU cycles.  Some applications can't handle that. Its something you would have to experiment with.

High should be less of a problem.  However, you still need to monitor your system to see if all the applications are behaving well.

Here is how to change the process via command line, which you can put into a shortcut:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191771

Comment: On Windows, it *does* starve other processes very easily (including Task Manager itself).

Comment: It all depends on your system.  Depending on how CPU intensive the process it, a realtime affinity is fine.  Im running a process in realtime right now with no issues.  Also, it can help to set an affinity to one processor while setting the priority to realtime.

Comment: If a process is set to realtime, will it be given absolute priority over all other processes on the core it's running on? I've been trying to find ways to dedicate one of my cores to Dwarf Fortress while it's running.

Comment: Link is dead "Sorry, page not found"

Answer (score 4):

I would say it depends. If you only have one core/CPU on your computer, and it's a CPU-intensive task, I wouldn't set it to realtime. High might be okay, but that needs experimenting.

If you have multiple cores, and the process is single threaded: go ahead, set it however you want. Your other cores will still be free, even when one core is at 100% load the whole time.

If you have multiple cores and the process is multi threaded: it will depend if all threads will have 100% load. Some programs have a 'manager' thread that dispatches work to other threads but doesn't do a lot of processing itself. That would leave one core nearly free and thus allow for high or real-time priority.

Other programs will try to take in all cores. In this case high might be fine, but it needs experimenting.

Even others will only take a particular number of cores and might not use all cores available. In this case high or real-time priority should be fine.

Unless you're on a single core, go ahead, experiment. Most of the time it won't hurt to set it to high or even real-time. You can set the affinity of a process (how many cores it can use) in task manager as well. This way you can better balance the load on your CPU. It can also help keep temperatures and power consumption down, etc.

Comment: +1 Good point that a single-threaded app is no problem on a multi-core machine, no matter how compute-bound.

Comment: Don't forget though, that as warned, [primarily] single threaded high priority processes - even if they affect only a single core - can hold global system synchronization locks for an abnormal amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Whether this will work for you depends entirely on what your application does.  If it's grinding through a long, long computation that never needs to wait for i/o, expect that running that at high priority could bring your machine to its knees.  But if the issue is latency and your application just needs to wake up really fast in response to an i/o completion or similar event, do a little quick processing and then go right back to sleep again, it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In general, every application that sets its primary process priority to anything other than normal will adversely affect everything else on your machine in terms of performance.  So if every application took this attitude of self-importance, eventually nothing would work properly.

The correct way to use higher priorities is in individually threaded TASKS, not in APPLICATIONS.  And these tasks should either run only as needed and then stop or suspend themselves when they have no work to do.  If when writing an application you feel you need to change a priority base level, then think very hard about how to make the interval where this is necessary as short as possible.

It may even be worth investing in a book or a course about concurrent and parallel processing before you go anywhere near something like priority hiking.